# docker-compose v3 + apache spark, connection refused on port 7077

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-swarm

I'm not sure if this is 100% programming or sysadmin related question.

I'm trying to setup a docker-compose file, in the version 3, for docker-swarm, docker version 1.13 to test spark for my local workflow.

Sadly the port 7077 does only get bound to localhost on my swarm cluster and so is not reachable from the outside world, where my spark app is trying to connect to it.

Does anyone have an idea, how to get docker-compose in swarm mode to bind to all interfaces?

I publish my ports and this works fine for say 8080, but not for 7070.

nmap output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-03-02 11:27 PST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000096s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8081/tcp open  blackice-icecap
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook
```

Explanation of ports

```
8081 is my spark worker
8080 is my spark master frontend
8888 is the spark hue frontend
```

nmap does not list 7077

Using netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1641/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::4040                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::6066                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1641/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::7077                 :::*                    LISTEN      1634/dockerd
```

And I can connect to 7077 over telnet on localhost without any issues, but outside of localhost I'm receiving a connection refused error.

At this point in time (please bear with me, I'm not a sysadmin, I'm a software guy), I'm starting to have the feeling this is somehow related to the docker mesh network.

Docker compose section for my master configuration:

```
#the spark master, having to run on the frontend of the cluster
 master:
  image: eros.fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu/spark
  command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h master
  hostname: master
  environment:
    MASTER: spark://master:7077
    SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: blonde.fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu
  ports:
    - 4040:4040
    - 6066:6066
    - 8080:8080
    - 7077:7077
  volumes:
    - /tmp:/tmp/data
  networks:
    - spark
    - frontends
  deploy:
    placement:
      #only run on manager node
      constraints:
        - node.role == manager
```

The networks spark and frontend are both overlay networks

Comment: >And I can connect to 7077 over telnet on localhost without any issues, but outside of localhost I'm receiving a connection refused error.
  --- 

Is the app binding to 127.0.0.1:7077? Try to change it to bind to 0.0.0.0:7077 instead

Comment: any suggestions how todo this in docker-compose file? It's really only a problem on docker swarm, it works without docker swarm fine

Comment: yeah, you should be able to set it as an env variable: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html look for SPARK_LOCAL_IP   (or spark.driver.bindAddress if you prefer to change the property instead), anyway this is just a guess, not saying is going to solve the problem unfortunately :(

Comment: thanks for your help, binding it to all interfaces (0.0.0.0) , helped to have it bind to the container ip, but sadly the forwarding from outside of the server is still not working

Comment: np, I am glad you've found the source of the problem at last !

Answer (score 2):

The issue was a configuration error in the docker-compose file. The -h master in the original configuration always bound to the local host interface.

Even after specifying the SPARK_LOCAL_IP value

```
 master:
  image: eros.fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu/spark:latest
  command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master 
  hostname: master
  environment:
    SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: blonde.fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu
    SPARK_LOCAL_IP: 0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - 4040:4040
    - 6066:6066
    - 8080:8080
    - 7077:7077
  volumes:
    - /tmp:/tmp/data
  deploy:
    placement:
      #only run on manager node
      constraints:
        - node.role == manager
```